# RoR - Project that exclusively uses another systems API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wrapper, rails-activerecord

Absolute beginner with ruby and with rails. My first full blown project will interface with an existing system through a REST api.

So it doesn't employ the normal ActiveRecord model and I was hoping for some examples of projects that replace the normal use of models with API calls. The entire CRUD set will require the app to make the corresponding API calls. I'd like to do this the right way, just don't know what that looks like yet.

Thanks! :)

Helpful links for googlers:

http://yetimedia.tumblr.com/post/35233051627/activeresource-is-dead-long-live-activeresource
https://github.com/rails/activeresource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any projects that are open source that do this, but I'd recommend looking into [Active Resource](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activeresource/README.rdoc). It was part of Rails through 3.2, but has been moved to a [separate repo](https://github.com/rails/activeresource) for Rails 4. The idea is that it lets you replace database persistance with RESTful APIs, which sounds like exactly what you're trying to do. There is some documentation [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/activeresource/3.2.12/frames) which should give you enough info to get off the ground. There's also a [pretty old Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics) on it, but I'm sure the concepts haven't really changed that much.

Here's an example from the docs that shows how to setup your "model":

```
class Person < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://api.people.com:3000"
end
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I need. Unfortunately, the RESTful API I'm interfacing with doesn't follow the conventions that ActiveResource expects. I'd end up writing custom REST methods a good amount of the time. Still the way to go, or is there another api wrapper solution to consider?

Comment: Good question and I think the answer depends on how much you want to override vs just rolling your own system. Is the API you're integrating with actually following REST conventions?

Comment: Well it's using delete for deletion and post for creation, but the URL structure does not appear to match the ActiveResource assumed conventions. Just wondering if creating a standalone ruby wrapper of the API, that I then use in rails, is worth the effort.

Comment: I'd recommend spending a little time with both approaches and see which one feels better after a few hours.

Comment: Thanks for the direction! Now I can begin stumbling towards mile marker 1. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest leveraging `ActiveModel` so your models aren't 'AR' backed, i.e. no persistance via AR.  You'll handle CRUD accordingly in your controllers and craft your own 'business logic' that you can tuck into your `ActiveModel`.